# How to specify a "field" parameter in a YoutubeService method

Tags: youtube-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I have a properly authorized YouTubeService that I can use to retrieve a list of videos for a "signed in" user. My issue is that I couldn't figure out how to filter out the response so I can lower down my consumption of my quota limit. In addition, I would only need to know a few detail of the videos. Here's what I got:

```
private static Google.Apis.Youtube.v3.YoutubeService _youtubeService;

public static void GetList(string id) {
    var response = _youtubeService.Videos.List(id, "snippet");

    // some processing happens here
}
```

I would like to include a filter using the fields parameter as described [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#fields). I only want to fetch the following fields: Snippet and it's title and thumbnails and effectively have: `fields=items(id,snippet(title,thumbnails(value)))` in my request.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 5):

Isn't the 'setFields' method (which should be a member of a large number of objects descending from YoutubeRequest) designed to do this? Something like this:

```
response.setFields("items(id,snippet/title,snippet/thumbnails/default/url)");
```

Comment: The `Videos.List` method returns a `ServiceRequest<VideoListResponse>` and it doesn't have a **setFields** method. Btw, I was referring to the tool that can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/APIs#YouTube_Data_API). I was browsing through the source code and I think the "fields" filtering is currently not supported in v3 of the [Youtube Google Api](http://contrib.google-api-dotnet-client.googlecode.com/hg/Stable/Generated/Source/Google.Apis.Youtube.v3.cs).

Comment: We may need confirmation on whether or not it's supported on the tool you're looking at; it certainly is part of the v3 API as a whole. This link: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.list seems to indicate that it's supported generally speaking. You're right about the setFields method, and that was my mistake; it shouldn't be executed on the response object, but instead on the request object before the request is sent.

Comment: Yes you are right on that one (re the link). I've played with it too and I know it's supported at least generally speaking, plus the other docs I linked says it should be possible. It's just that they did not include it in the dotnet client. I hope the Google Dotnet team is watching this. It's very important they include it. I am watching my API usage as I test our app and our current code's api usage is a bit high for what we're trying to do.